# How to load webpage in VB and automatically log in?

Tags: vb.net, email

I have an application that will open a webpage using the Web browser control and automatically login the users information, for example gmail. I plan on having 3 choices the user can enter: Gmail, Twitter and Facebook. All the do it type in their username and password and click one of the options above, and their account will automatically be signed in. The problem I am experiencing is that when my application loads, so does gmail, so if the user wants to login to facebook, it would be awkward to see Gmail automatically loaded in the form instead, right? So I took `        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1") from the private form, and wanted to add it into my button called gmail. So the button would look like this:

```
 Private Sub btnGmail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGmail.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1")

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value", txtEmail.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Passwd").SetAttribute("value", txtPasswd.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

However I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   Which from some Googling showed that it meant there was something NULL in my form? But everything is filled in, so I don't understand why? In my code, it underlines the "txtEmail.Text" part on the 3rd line, but I'm filling it in?

So now I am left clueless as to have the user click the button "GMAIL" so it will load gmail and proceed to input the information they type in the email and passwd textbox.

Comment: Your code makes the assumption that `GetElementById` is successful, and just uses it without checking. If it doesn't, it returns null, and you then try to use `SetAttribute` on that null reference. Are you absolutely certain that there is an element named `Email` in the document? (Examine it in your web browser's development tool.)

Comment: @KenWhite I know the element must exist because the project works completely fine when the navigate() function is in the private form and not in the button called btnGmail, so it seems where that is placed is somehow messing it up? I don't understand why the placement as to where the site is navigated at should effect the txtPasswd and txtEmail text boxes

Comment: No, you *assume* the element exists, until you confirm that it does after the call to Navigate in your button event. Do what I suggested, and **confirm it** using the developer tools in your web browser. Pass the **exact** URL you're providing to Navigate, and then examine the DOM to see if the element exists by that name, instead of just assuming it exists. It takes about two seconds to confirm, and you're not guessing any more.

Comment: ` <input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" value="" spellcheck="false" ` I do believe this is the element I am looking for. This is using the EXACT link in navigate()